# OG context not passed in Entity Reference View Widget

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups, navigation

I am using [Entity Reference View Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module (ERVW) and set its view to have two args, 1st arg being the "Content: nid" set to "display all" on no filter value while the 2nd arg is "OG Membership: Group ID" set to "Get OG from context" on no filter value.

Aside this, I have set a contextual link on the group page "Add Something" using [Contextual Admin OG module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_admin_og) and page manager. Along with this on group content type, the og_group_ref field is pre-populated by checking the option "OG Context" using Entity Reference Prepopulate module.

Now on the node add form (reached through the above "Add Something" link on group page), the og_group_ref is populating correctly but ***when I click "Add Items" link for ERVW, it does not get OG from context*** hence resulting in listing all content (nodes). However, being nid as 1st arg and "Pass select ID into view" option selected in field settings, the selected node in modal window is exempted from the list when the modal window opened again. So the passing ID thing is working fine.

Further, if I set a fixed value of OG it does filter the content and pass selected IDs into view as well. I have tried to get Raw Value and Content ID from URL with no luck. Can somebody point me in the right direction?